# "The system cannot find the path specified" в задачах invoke

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pyinvoke

Портирую задачи, написанные с помощью [invoke](http://www.pyinvoke.org/) (v 0.21), c *nix на Windows.
Любое использование `ctx.run` приводит к исключению.

tasks.py:

```
from invoke import task

@task
def hello(ctx):
    ctx.run('echo Hello')
```

Результат одинаковый как в Git bash, так и в cmd.exe:

```
C:\...>invoke hello

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python36\Scripts\invoke.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\invoke\program.py", line 293, in run
    self.execute()
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\invoke\program.py", line 414, in execute
    executor.execute(*self.tasks)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\invoke\executor.py", line 129, in execute
    result = call.task(*args, **call.kwargs)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\invoke\tasks.py", line 115, in __call__
    result = self.body(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\...\tasks.py", line 5, in hello
    ctx.run('echo Hello')
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\invoke\context.py", line 82, in run
    return self._run(runner, command, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\invoke\context.py", line 89, in _run
    return runner.run(command, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\invoke\runners.py", line 262, in run
    return self._run_body(command, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\invoke\runners.py", line 276, in _run_body
    self.start(command, shell, env)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\invoke\runners.py", line 981, in start
    stdin=PIPE,
  File "c:\python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "c:\python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 992, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified
```

Хотя вот так ошибок нет:

```
C:\...>echo Hello
Hello
```

Вот что в переменной `%PATH%`:

> C:\Python36\Scripts\;C:\Python36\;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Code Collaborator Client;C:\Program Files (x86)\CollabNet Subversion;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;

А если запускаю cmd через Git bash, то так:

> C:\Users\nvolynkin\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\nvolynkin\bin;C:\Python36\Scripts;C:\Python36;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Code Collaborator Client;C:\Program Files (x86)\CollabNet Subversion;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl

Я проверил все пути в обеих версиях `%PATH%`. Пары директорий не было, я их создал, но проблема осталась.

Куда копать дальше?

---

Заодно было бы интеренсо узнать, что за терминал используется в вызовах `ctx.run`? Похоже, что это cmd.exe, но не тот же, который я запускаю по `Win+R > cmd` или открывая `cmd.exe` из Git bash.

Comment: Пока что поиск привёл меня сюда: [Fix for wrong shell in Windows](https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/pull/407)

Comment: `echo` `copy` и т п не являются исполнимыми модулями. Их правильно бы было выполнять так `cmd.exe /c echo params`. В некоторых случаях  лучше запустить cmd и перенаправить ввод вывод.

Comment: В статье упомянута ещё одна особенность, переменная окружения COMSPEC содержит полный пусть и имя процессора cmd.exe

Comment: @nick_n_a я установил Git for Windows с опцией "переписать команды cmd.exe", так что в cmd.exe команда `which echo` возвращает `/usr/bin/echo`. Кстати, про какую статью вы говорите?

Comment: Имел ввиду ссылку  Fix for wrong shell in Windows

Comment: @nick_n_a а, тогда понял. Я нашёл заплатку, кстати.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема известна и чинится в пулл-реквесте [Fix for wrong shell in Windows](https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/pull/407).

Пока что можно патчить декоратор `task` непосредственно во время выполнения.
Код взят из репозитория [datakortet/dk-tasklib](https://github.com/datakortet/dk-tasklib/blob/cb5ffbc6a6535f5287f876df860fd67c2e7a26b2/dktasklib/wintask.py).
Поскольку invoke 0.21 уже выпущен, но проблема в нём не исправлена, я поднял версию в условии до 22.

```
import invoke
from invoke import task as _task


if invoke.__version_info__ < (0, 22):
    # https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/pull/407
    from invoke import Context

    if not getattr(Context, '_patched', False):
        Context._patched = True
        _orig_run = Context.run


        def run(self, command, **kwargs):
            if sys.platform == 'win32':
                kwargs['shell'] = os.environ['COMSPEC']
            return _orig_run(self, command, **kwargs)

        Context.run = run

task = _task
```

Если нужно выполнять задачи **только** на Windows, то можно обойти проблему проще.

1. Создайте файл конфигурации `invoke.yml` в той же директории, что и `tasks.py`.
2. В него добавьте следующий код:

   ```
   run:
     shell: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
   ```